# how to set tab button max-height: 20px; CSS

Tags: css

```
  body .tab ul.tab-nav li a {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: inherit;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5%;
    top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background:  rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
}
```

This is my CSS code, when i add  `max-height: 20px;` the text goes out of the button?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided the mark up along with the CSS

Comment: and why are you surprised ? you added a limit to the height, so you get overflow if the text is bigger

Comment: no is not that, the text is not that big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's the `padding: 13px 20px;` You're defining that the max-height can only be `20px`, but you're also specifying the `a` will have `13px` of padding on the top, and `13px` of padding on the bottom which should be 23px height with padding. Try adjusting the padding, on lower top/bottom dimensions: `padding: 5px 20px`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is working like this  padding: 0 10px;

Comment: Glad to hear it!